# warning: (343) implicit return at end of non-void function

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, microchip, xc8

I am getting above warning when the pointer token is returned from the function. The below code is not complete, shorten to avoid confusion.

```
  char *ServerResponds()        
    {
        char copy_wifi_data[EUSART_BUFFER_SIZE];                               
        uint16_t i = 0; int tok_count = 0;            

        static char *token;
        token = strtok(copy_wifi_data, ":");               //Converting wifi data to tokens.

        while(token != NULL)
        {  
            if(tok_count == 1)
            {
                return token;
            }

            token = strtok(NULL,":");  
            tok_count++;
        } 
    }
```

Comment: What if the condition is never true? What does the function return?

Comment: @tkausl the function returns a pointer to string. I have not written an else statement as it is not necessary.

Comment: If there is elided code here you should indicate with `...`.  This code is not otherwise plausible - `copy_wifi_data` for example is not initialised, and `i` is unused.  Moreover what is the purpose of declaring `token` `static`?  Has a bit of a code smell about it.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPS : You have missed the point - tkausl was referring to the conditin to the `while`.  If the first `strtok()` returns `NULL`, the while loop will not be entered, and the function ends with no explicit return. You may intend for it to never happen in practice, but the compiler cannot know that, and frankly neither can you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning occurs because there is no return statement in the case that `tok_count == 1` is false.

```
char *ServerResponds()        
{
    char copy_wifi_data[EUSART_BUFFER_SIZE];                               
    uint16_t i = 0; int tok_count = 0;            

    static char *token;
    token = strtok(copy_wifi_data, ":");               

    while(token != NULL)
    {  
        if(tok_count == 1)
        {
            return token;
        }

        token = strtok(NULL,":");  
        tok_count++;
    } 
    /* <--- there is no return if control flow reaches this point */

}
```

You could add a `return 0;` at the end of the function to address this, but you would have to document this behavior and be sure that the callers are prepared to handle a null return value.

Comment: why `return 0;` instead of `return NULL;`? it is true that this is the same for the compiler but visually more recognisable what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

The function does not return a value via all possible execution paths.

While you could ass a `return NULL` or `return token` after the while loop, it might be considered bad practice to have multiple return points from a single function - it is contrary to many common coding standards, and ill-advised in most cases.

```
    //Converting wifi data to tokens.
    static char *token  = strtok(copy_wifi_data, ":");               
    while( tok_count == 0; token != NULL )
    {  
        token = strtok(NULL,":");  
        tok_count++;
    }

    return token ;
```

That said it is not clear what the purpose of the while loop is, or why `token` is `static`. It is semantically the same as:

```
    //Converting wifi data to tokens.
    char *token = strtok(copy_wifi_data, ":");               
    if( token != NULL )
    {  
        token = strtok(NULL,":");  
    }

    return token ;
```